# Synchronous POST method with Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I am sending pin number to my local server using Volley APIs (for completing phone number registration process) as mentioned below

```
final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("PHONE_NUMBER",1234567890);
params.put("PIN", 9999);

addRequestToQueue("http://"127.0.0.1:5000"/registerClient", params);


public void addRequestToQueue(String url, final HashMap<String, String> params)
{

JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {VolleyLog.v("Response from server: %s", response.toString());}},new Response.ErrorListener() {@Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {VolleyLog.e("Error:", error.toString());}});


mRequestQueue.add(jsonRequest);

}
```

This is working fine and storing information on server but i am unable to get the response code/string from server. Probably it is because of Asynchronous call...

would someone please help me to resolve the issue, i need to get the response string/code from server so that i can verify that user properly registered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url,  new JSONObject(params), future, future)
mRequestQueue.add(request);

try {
    JSONObject response = future.get();
      ... do something
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The solution provided is working but my application halted at JSONObject response = future.get(); I am not able to do anything after that....

Comment: Try to add a timeout ...  future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); where the number is the timeout in seconds

Comment: Thanks for your response, just before testing "future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS). I wanted to ask a question, should i call this in a separate thread... currently i am calling the method at "button Press".

Comment: No because Volley by using the queue request performs all http request in another thread. You can call it everywhere, Volley doesn't require another thread like Retrofit

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried it but always getting TimeoutException ... :(((

Comment: Are you sure that your web service works fine? To do a Sync Http Req with Volley the code above is fine, if you get TimeoutException seems that your server doesn't response. Could you try to check your server call with Postam to be sure that it works fine.

Comment: yes i am receiving Advance Rest Client (plugin of chrome). I am able to get response from server in response section... but this is not the case if am using my android code mentioned above :((

Comment: I am also getting the time out exception.If i am using different thread that was working good.I need a solution,How to do the synchronous network calling using volley?